# Document the effective pipeline definition from nested templates

Tags: azure-pipelines

Many of the teams in my organization make use of nested YAML templates in their pipeline definitions.  In some cases, we're talking about a dozen or more YAML templates in multiple repositories that call each other.  Tracking down each of these YAML templates and then finding each of the nested templates inside of those templates can be very tedious and time consuming.

Does anyone have or know of any sort of tool that would put automate the process of finding all these nested templates and putting together either a monolithic singular template that include everything or create a diagram of all the relationships (or both)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything that will map the relationships between templates.

If you want to see the full YAML you can do this in the YAML editor.

Go to your pipeline and click "Edit"

Hit the 3 dots next to the "run" button and select "Download full YAML" this will generate a YAML File that contains all of the templates referenced by the main YAML file in the pipeline

[image: Full YAML]

You can open this in a text editor to see what the build will do at runtime